# Is it possible for a feature not correlated with a dependent variable to become important in a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, machine-learning-model, correlation, feature-importances

Is it possible for a feature not correlated (or faintly correlated) with a dependent variable to become important in a machine learning model?

Comment: It depends on the variable and the problem you are analyzing. Can you provide ad example dataset?

Comment: This is a general question, not specific to any data. Is it a possibility?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer with an example where non-correlated data become important feature in the model

Comment: In my example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/621366/247274), neither feature has any correlation with the color, yet the two features, jointly, almost perfectly predict the color.

Answer (score 0):

Suppressor variables are an example. Two good explanations are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/suppression-effect-in-regression-definition-and-visual-explanation-depiction) and [here](http://jse.amstat.org/v22n2/ludlow.pdf) but you can search and find a bunch more references.

A common view is a suppressor sharpens another variables relationship to the target. The suppressor is correlated with another feature and not the target but the correlation is in the area of the residuals of the other feature to the target.